# Error sending object to JAX-RS using JQuery and JSON

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jax-rs

I'm trying to send a javascript object to a JAX-RS server. I get a server-side exception when i PUT from jquery.

Here is my server code

```
//JAX-RS Server
@PUT
@Path("/edit/{project_key}/")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response editAssociation(@PathParam("project_key") String projectKey,
    @FormParam("association") EditFieldAssociationModel association) {
        //TODO
        //Here i just put a debug break point
        return Response.noContent().build();
}

//EditFieldAssociationModel class    
@XmlRootElement(name = "EditFieldAssociationModel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EditFieldAssociationModel {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @XmlElement(name = "method")
    private String method;

    @XmlElement(name = "jiraDefaultValue")
    private String jiraDefaultValue;

    @XmlElement(name = "externalDefaultValue")
    private String externalDefaultValue;

    //and public accessors
}
```

And my js code :

```
function(){
    var editasso = {id:asso_id,
            method:d.find(".sync-plugin-method").find('select').val(),
            jiraDefaultValue:d.find('.sync-plugin-jira-default-value').find('select').val(),
            externalDefaultValue:d.find('.sync-plugin-external-default-value').find('select').val()};

    AJS.$.ajax({
          url: AJS.contextPath()+"/rest/a-sync-rest/1.0/association/edit/"+getProjectKey(),
          type: "PUT",
          //TODO

          data: JSON.stringify(editasso),
          beforeSend: function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                  //x.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                  x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                  console.log("mime type override ok");
                }else{
                    console.log("unable to override mime type");
                }
           },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg){
              dialog.remove();
              location.reload();
          },
          error : sync_plugin_error
    });
}
```

I tried with other values for editasso

```
var editasso = {association : {id:asso_id,
                        method:d.find(".sync-plugin-method").find('select').val(),
                        jiraDefaultValue:d.find('.sync-plugin-jira-default-value').find('select').val(),
                        externalDefaultValue:d.find('.sync-plugin-external-default-value').find('select').val()}};
```

The post body seems to be correct :

```
{"association":{"id":"350","method":"com.a.jira.synchronization.KeepLatestSyncMethod","jiraDefaultValue":"Valeur 1","externalDefaultValue":"aa"}}
```

The exception is

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

Any suggestion ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved : the EditFieldAssociationModel must not use the same annotation than the server-to-client class. Now, my class looks like :

```
public class EditFieldAssociationModel {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("method")
    private String method;

    @JsonProperty("jiraDefaultValue")
    private String jiraDefaultValue;

    @JsonProperty("externalDefaultValue")
    private String externalDefaultValue;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And it works